# Is it natural to use the phrasal verb "give back" when I lent something it somehody and I want it back?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is it natural to use the phrasal verb *give back* when I lent something it somehody and I want it back? For example:

> Do you remember the drill I lend you? Could you **give** it **back**?

If it's not really natural, what would a native English speaker say?

Comment: It's fine. But note that we commonly hear *Give it back!* in the context of someone (often a *child*) having taken something *without authorisation*, so it will tend to carry at least *overtones* of "petulant children arguing over toys". But children don't normally say things like *Could you please return it?*, so you might be safer with that.

Comment: Or "Could you let me have it back, please?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is perfectly fine. But, it's not a phrasal verb!
As we know phrasal verb can give an entirely different meaning to the words. In your case `give back` is not just getting things back. The phrasal verb form of `giving/give back` means:

> To contribute something to a community, foundation, or charity.

Hence, when you say, `Could you give me my money back?` or `Could you return it?` or even `May I have it back?` is fine but not the use of phrasal verb. You can use it in below form:

> She gives back to her community by volunteering at the local schools and donating to charity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Gave you thumbs up. You could improve by mentioning something like "return it."

Comment: Thanks, updated the response.